# How to check if value exists in MySQL Database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to PHP but I like to create a script that checks if an email is in my MySQL Database, the Database name is `"Fily_Registrations"`, the table is "users" and the value is called `"email"`. So basically if an the email `"hi@all.com"` exists in my database and I call the php script like `"http://path/to/php.php?email=hi@all.com"` it should echo out `"YES"` if it don't exists it should echo out `"NO"`.

This is how fare I am now, but it always echoes out "NO":

```
<?php

$email = $_GET["email"];
$DataBase = "Fily_Registrations";
mysql_connect("server", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($DataBase) or die(mysql_error());
$string = sprintf("SELECT '$DataBase' FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
$query = msql_query($string);
if($query == false) {
     echo("No");
} else {
    echo("Yes");
}
?>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: May be mysql_num_rows($query) and check if its 0 then no data else there are ?

Comment: The code is very vulnerable. There are multiple attack vectors here: you're using `sprintf()` without arguments and interpolating user-defined values into the query without escaping them.

Comment: There seems to be a problem in your query syntax.
It should be SELECT [column_name] FROM [table_name] WHERE [condition]
and not SELECT [db_name] FROM [table_name] WHERE [condition]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If database is Fily_Registrations then the query is wrong. Try this:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape($_GET["email"]);
$DataBase = "Fily_Registrations";
mysql_connect("server", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($DataBase) or die(mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) ? 'NO' : 'YES';
```

mysql_query returns false if query is not correct. Read first https://www.php.net/mysql_query and consider using PDO (https://www.php.net/pdo) instead of normal mysql_query.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this:

```
<?php

$email = $_GET["email"];
$DataBase = "Fily_Registrations";
mysql_connect("server", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($DataBase) or die(mysql_error());
$string = mysql_real_escape("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
$query = msql_query($string);
if($query) {
     echo mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ? "YES" : "NO";
} else {
    echo("====some error===");
}
?>
```

mysql_num_rows : http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php
mysql_real_escape: http://pt2.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: A good answer should address this issue. Please do so. And don't just copy-and-paste the OP's code and make corrections. Instead, *explicitly* hint at `mysql_num_rows()` and tell him/her its significance.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet super safe, but better.

- Email checked for unsafe quotes with mysql_real_escape. Don't place too much trust on this thought. Some additional regex checking could be in order.
- Prepared statements don't allow hidden mysql code execution from within parameters.

  ```
  $email = mysql_real_escape($_GET["email"]);
  try {
   $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=server;dbname=Fily_Registrations;port=3306", "user", "password");
  }catch(PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
  }

  $q= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :EMAIL";
  $statement = $connect->prepare($q);
  $status = $statement->execute(array(":EMAIL"=>$email));

  if (($status) && ($statement->rowCount() > 0))
  {
    echo "YES";
  } else {
    echo "NO";
  }
  ```

Br,
Kari